# Android : Get users to update apps by releasing more frequently?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the store that I want my users to upgrade quickly.  I have made several updates before and things went smoothly: in about a week 80% of my users had the new app.  Now, however, I have more users and they are taking longer to update to the new version.  It has been about 3 weeks and only 55% are using the new app.  I know that I could put out a message within the app saying "hey you should really update the app", but I'm also wondering: If I release a small bug-fix update do you think I will get more people to update?  If I release again will a new notification go to them saying they have an update available for my app?  Is this a good idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is too broad and doesn't really belong here, but anyway:
I would not update your app more frequently if it's not necessary, and I would especially **not** nag your users by frequently displaying an update notification if it's just bugfixes or minor improvements. (It's different if your users really need to update for functionality, but I guess that's not the case here).

Simply put: it's not in your hands if your users update, and imho it shouldn't be. Provide value with each update, and if your users feel it's worth it, they will update.